# How to get runid status of databricks job by powershell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

```
Install-Module -Name DatabricksPS
$accessToken = "dapi123456789be672c4007052d4694a7c51"
$apiUrl = "https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net"
Set-DatabricksEnvironment -AccessToken $accessToken -ApiRootUrl $apiUrl
Start-DatabricksCluster -ClusterID "1202-211320-brick1"
Start-DatabricksJob -JobID xxxxxxxxxxxx
Get-DatabricksJobRun -JobID xxxxxxxxxxxxx | Get-DatabricksJobRunOutput
```

I want to the notebook status (pass or failed) when running from powershell script.Runid is dynamic.How can i get the status of job

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: revoke the access token

Comment: You can leverage jobs api provided by Databricks.
More info: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli.html
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your script. I reproduced it and above script is **working fine** for me.

[image]

I got all the runs of this job and their status.

If you are not getting it try to **revoke the access token** as suggested by **@Alex Ott**.

Other than using Powershell, you can directly view the runid and status of the job in the **Databricks UI**.

Go to **Workflows** -> **Jobs** -> select your job.

[image]